# How to deploy msi through jenkins

Tags: jenkins

i want to deploy MSi through jenkins,can anyone tell me about this how will do it.i have installed MS build plugin,but not sure if this can be 
used only to build MSI or deploy as well

thanks
Robinder singh

Answer (score 1):

You can create a command line call and use this for reference:
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpCmdLineMSI.htm

Once you have your command working within the particular ISE(powershell) or CMD prompt create a new job and paste the code within one of the build events with the respective execution method selected.

Comment: If you are trying to utilize msbuild for a visual studio solution and not install an msi you can utilize a similar technique but reference the msbuild documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx